# How do I call a specific element in an array list in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

If I have an array list like

```
ArrayList <Student> list = new ArrayList <Student>();
Student s1 = new Student("Alex S",  "Smashing smile", 12);
Student s2 = new Student("James L", "Beautiful voice", 12);
Student s3 = new Student("Alex C",  "Star VB player", 12);
```

How can I call the element with index 2 (the number) for each particular instance of Student?

Comment: For each particular instance? Do you just mean the list.get(2); method?

Comment: `list.get(2)` ? You should take a look at the doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html. If you want to have all the numbers of your student instances, you should implement a for loop. `for(Student s : list) System.out.println(s.getNumber());`

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<E>` has `public E get(int index)` function: which returns the element at the specified position in this list.

```
list.add(s1);
list.add(s2);
list.add(s3);
Student student = list.get(2);
```

Check the [ArrayList class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) documentation for other function.

Answer (score 1):

When you [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) an Object from the `ArrayList`, you get.. the *Object* itself.

Assuming you have a method that returns this number, you do:

```
list.get(2).getNumber(); //Where getNumber() returns this 12 you want..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `get(int index)`. Pay attention to the fact that the first element of the ArrayList has index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Call X.get(2) where X = {instance1, instance2, instance3, ...}. I know now way to have it called for all instances at once.